# Can't write in terminal

Tags: gnome, 13.04, gnome-terminal

I've just installed Ubuntu 13.04 Gnome, 64 bits on my computer (keeping my old /home partition). But the providen gnome-terminal has a strange behaviour : it does not show me the prompt, and I can't write onto it !!!

[image]

Is it a bad installation issue or a bug ?

Regards

Comment: What about trying another terminal emulator? And did you try to login the console at `Ctrl+Alt+F1` or `Ctrl+Alt+F2`?

Comment: Thank you for your answer : in fact i had also installed the vte terminal ROXTerm : which is very well indeed :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your text and background colors are both black. Go to *Edit -> Profile Preferences*. There, disable the "*use colors from system theme*".

If that worked you should check the colors of the system theme, but this is beyond the scope here.

Comment: Thank you very much :) I did not think about this possibility.